# Why does this URL work in Django? It is not in urls.py

Tags: django, routes

I've never worked with Django before. I'm taking over a Django project that was started by another programmer, who is now long gone. There is some magic happening in the code that I do not understand. For instance, in this file:

```
urls.py
```

I see this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
from core import views as core_views
from sugarlab.search.views import validate_collections, create_document, delete_interest, rename_interest, add_url, my_interests
from sugarlab.search.views import content, score, terms
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout as django_logout
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/logout/$', django_logout,
        {'next_page': '/'}),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', django_logout,
        {'next_page': '/'}),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^unsecured/$', core_views.home),
```

The confusing part is these two lines:

```
from django.conf import settings

url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

"allauths" is some configuration set inside of this file:

```
settings/common.py
```

The data looks like this:

```
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sites',
# Social/3rd party Authentication apps                                                                                                        
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
'captcha'
```

Somehow this is a URL that actually works:

```
/accounts/signup/
```

This file is completely blank:

```
settings/__init__.py
```

So I've two questions:

1. how does "import settings" manage to magically import allauths?
2. how does `/accounts/signup/` map to an actual view? I don't see anything in urls.py, nor in settings, that would make me think that `/accounts/signup/` is a valid url.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your urls.py is explicitly including the allauth URLs explicitly under /accounts/. There's nothing magic going on. Importing settings has nothing to do with anything here.

Comment: Where does allauth come from? It isn't a file. It is inside of settings/common.py.

Comment: No it isn't. It is an app that you have installed, that is in your project's Python path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does /accounts/signup/ map to an actual view? I don't see anything in urls.py, nor in settings, that would make me think that /accounts/signup/ is a valid url.

url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

there is another urls file inside the app called allauth if it's installed by "pip" you can find it in the following directory "lib/python*/site-package/allauth"

- = the python version you are using for example 2.7 or 3.5

ps allauth is a well known 3rd party app you can quick google search django allauth and you'll find it

> how does "import settings" manage to magically import allauths?

it doesnt import settings is used for something else for example setting static file url like that

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```